# PMD Gradle Plugin: Remove pmdTest upon gradle check

Tags: gradle, pmd

I am using the PMD Gradle plugin in a build.gradle file. Is there a way to disable the pmdTest task so that it is not run I execute `gradle check` ?

Edit: In the question I say 'remove'. I really mean 'disable'.

Comment: For a discussion on this topic, please see this [forum post](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_remove_a_task_dependency).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
pmd {
    sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
}
```

See [PmdExtension](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.PmdExtension.html) in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: This still ran the pmdTest task and still evaluated clases under src/test/java.

Comment: I ended up adding:

    <exclude-pattern>.*//*src/test/java*//*.*</exclude-pattern>

To my pmd-rules.xml file.

Comment: I just double-checked, and it worked as expected. With `pmd.sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]`, `gradle check` no longer ran `pmdTest` but only `pmdMain`.

Comment: I added your fix directly in the pmd.gradle file. Is this where you added?

Comment: Peter, your fix worked for me after adding in my pmd.gradle file. Not sure what I did wrong the first time. Are there cons to my solution?

Comment: I'd say it's nicer/clearer not to run the `pmdTest` task than to run it and make it do nothing. Also, after setting `pmd.sourceSets` you can still run `pmdTest` directly when desired.